# What's the difference between the Maven Android builds and Eclipse Android builds

Tags: android, maven

If I use Eclipse to create Android Release builds,the builds' size is 10Mb, and for the debug builds, the size is 11Mb.
However, if I use Maven to include the jars, both the release and debug builds are about 11Mb. and if I use system scope to include the jars, the apk file will not work well.
Does anyone know how this happens?
Thanks.